# Can I use AWS Device Farm with WebdriverIO Mobile testing?

Tags: mobile, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

I have a webdriverIO framework built. I am trying to setup a webdriverIO config file to connect to AWS Device Farm, and obtaining a mobile device, then running the appium based tests.

Maybe something like this? for the config file for iOS?
But the issue I have is the following:

1. How do I point to the IPA file that I have uploaded to the server?
2. How do I connect to the AWS Device Farm?
3. Is it safe to assume since AWS Device Farm runs an appium server, the supported capabilities is what I should use from appium?

```
const { join } = require('path');
const { config } = require('./wdio.conf');

config.specs = [
    './tests/specs/**/*.spec.js',
];

config.capabilities = [
    {
        platformName: 'iOS',
        maxInstances: 1,
        'appium:deviceName': 'iPhone 12',
        'appium:platformVersion': '14.4',
        'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
        'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest',
        'appium:app': 'replace this with your locally built app - full path to app file',
//        'appium:app': join(process.cwd(), './apps/iOS-Simulator-NativeDemoApp-0.2.1.app.zip'),
        'appium:noReset': true,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
    },
];

exports.config = config;
```

Answer (score 2):

For these questions:

1. How do I point to the IPA file that I have uploaded to the server?

AWS Device Farm uses a server-side execution platform, where you upload your app and test code using the CreateUpload API (ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUpload.html).

2. How do I connect to the AWS Device Farm?

You do not connect to AWS Device Farm from your local client, you Schedule a run on Device Farm using the ScheduleRun API (ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleRun.html)

3. Is it safe to assume since AWS Device Farm runs an appium server, the supported capabilities is what I should use from appium?

Yes, Device Farm executes your test on a server-side platform using an Appium server at localhost:4723

Please see this blog post for a detailed walk-through that should clarify some of these things for you: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/testing-mobile-apps-with-cucumber-and-appium-through-testng-on-aws-device-farm/